# Does the Honeycomb android:hardwareAccelerated="true" manifest setting apply for Live Wallpapers?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, live-wallpaper, hardware-acceleration

I have a live wallpaper that I originally coded to use canvas rendering for phone-sized screens. But when running it on a Xoom tab the framerate degrades noticeably, presumably due to the increased screen resolution.

I tried adding *android:hardwareAccelerated="true"* to the application element of my manifest, however the framerate remains degraded. Checking the canvas object Android passes to my WallpaperEngineHelper class' onDraw method shows that the canvas is indeed not accelerated:

```
    @Override
    protected void onDrawFrame(Canvas c) {
        c.isHardwareAccelerated(); //returns false
        ...
```

Am I missing something or should I re-code with a GL surface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Romain mentions that this is not supported in 3.0 in [this group discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/8afe3907110a0e3).

Chet Haase [recently posted](http://graphics-geek.blogspot.com/2011/08/droidflakes-android-animation-demo.html) about some hardware acceleration profiling.  The sample code may be of use to you.